# Configuring proxy.cgi in Windows using Apache and GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, proxy, apache

I want to dispaly my layers on a server. I'am using geoserver 2.3.2 and apache 2.4

Till now i Create a proxy file in referring in this link : http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi  and i Put it in cgi-bin folder.  I Installed python and in the starting line of proxy.cgi i put the location of python.  #!C:/Python27/python.exe -u

I found in some tutorials that i should configure the file httpd.conf  and i have no idea how to configure it and where should i add this code :

" ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

Order deny,allow

Allow from all

ProxyPass /geoserver //localhost:8080/geoserver

ProxyPassReverse /geoserver //localhost:8080/geoserver "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those settings look like they belong to an Apache 2.2 server. For your Apache 2.4 server you could instead try:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy /geoserver>
Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
```

Which are part of the configuration settings for Apache and added to the httpd.conf file.

You could try also using the server IP or localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 in the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse sections, i.e.

```
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
```

or

```
ProxyPass /geoserver http://<your server ip>:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://<your server ip>:8080/geoserver
```

To test whether the proxying of GeoServer via Apache is working you should browse to:

```
http://localhost/geoserver/web/
```

If this page opens then the Apache web server is correctly proxying the the GeoServer server.

To help you debug any issues with the Apache configuration open a command window and try:

```
httpd.exe -t
```

If you get an error "is not recognized as an internal or external command" then the Apache httpd.exe is not in your path, you will need to change to the directory that holds the httpd.exe file before running the command. The typical location for the httpd.exe file would be in the bin sub folder such as:

```
* C:\Apache24\bin\
```

Check too that at the top of the httpd.conf file that you have uncommented (remove the #) the modules that handle proxying like:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Answering other questions raised in the comments:

The call to the proxy.cgi file (like below) needs to go into your JavaScript code called by the HTML page in which you create your map.

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=..."
```

The proxy.cgi file itself doesn't need to be placed in the cgi-bin folder of the Apache server; it can go anywhere but you need to enable this by editing the following directive in the Apache httpd.conf file like below (where "C:/Apache24/htdocs" is taken to be the document root).

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs">
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  
    # Please see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    #Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes

    # Adding +ExecCGI allows CGI scripts to run outside of cgi-bin (and similar) script folders
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To enable the proxy.cgi file to be recognized as executable you need to uncomment the appropriate AddHandler section (within the <IfModule mime_module> section), like:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    ...
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    # Enabling the below to allow python processing
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
    ...
</IfModule>
```

You need to restart Apache for the configuration changes to be enabled.

You can test that the proxy.cgi is working by browsing to it like (below), without any parameters.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi
```

The page should redirect you to the [OpenLayers home page](http://www.openlayers.org), or whatever url you have set in the proxy.cgi section:

```
else:
    fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
    url = fs.getvalue('url', "http://www.openlayers.org")
```

For a working example of a Web page with OpenLayers using a proxy.cgi script see:
[GeoRSS Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/georss.html)

Comment: thanks for reply..but where should i add the code exactly ?!!

Comment: At the bottom your httpd.conf file.

Comment: after those modification when i want to start my apache, an error message come up whit : "The requested operation has failed!" do i miss something or what ?!

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the whole configuration.  Before you made the change to the Apache configuration were both the Apache http server  (http://127.0.0.1/) and the Java (Tomcat?) server (http://127.0.0.1/geoserver) working for you?  Do you get any warning if you use: httpd.exe -t in the command window?

Comment: nn (127.0.0.1/geoserver) didn't work for me !! here is what it works for me : http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ !! what about tomcat should i install Tomcat too

Comment: No need to install Tomcat if localhost:8080/geoserver is working for you (I assume you must be running geoserver using Jetty). So Geoserver is working, and now you need to get the Apache web server working correctly.  You say that 127.0.0.1/geoserver isn't working, but what about just http://127.0.0.1/ .  If that isn't working trying running httpd.exe -t in the command window. This will tell you if you have any misconfiguration in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 display a blank page with "It Works' !! for the command httpd.exe-t it shows a message "is not recognized as an internal or external command"...

Comment: it will be greatfuf if you tell me the steps that i have to follow to attend my intention

Comment: sorry but where is the httpd.exe file ? what i have here is httpd.txt in Apache2.4/conf !! for the path wath i have to modify exactly ? add a new environment variable or modify an existing variable ?

Comment: another quetion : in the file proxy.cgi what should i add exactly in "allowedHosts" ?? thank you a lot :)

Comment: where should i add exactly this line : OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

Comment: well when i execute the command it shows to me "Syntax OK" but when i modify the httpd.conf the server couldn't start ! i follow your advices and it doesn't work !! any ideas ?! and what about installing python in my server ?! i already installed but i dont know if it's installed on the sever or not because the proxy file written in python...

Comment: If the Apache server doesn't start after you have modified the Apache conf file, running httpd.exe -t should inform you where the error is in the Apache conf file.

Comment: here is what it shows to me this time :       AH00526:Syntax error on line 1 of "C:/...": invalid command 'ProxyRequests', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: now the server has started thanks a lot !! but how can i know that the connection is done between the apache and geoserver ?! im just a beginner and im sorry sir ! really thank you a loooot :)

Comment: here the allowedHosts in my proxy file :                   allowedHosts = ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs','localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', 'www.openlayers.org', 'openlayers.org',               'labs.metacarta.com', 'world.freemap.in', 'prototype.openmnnd.org', 'geo.openplans.org',               'sigma.openplans.org', 'demo.opengeo.org',
'www.openstreetmap.org','sample.azavea.com'                'www.openstreetmap.org','sample.azavea.com',              'v2.suite.opengeo.org','v-swe.uni-muenster.de:8080',            'vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org','www.openrouteservice.org']

Comment: it worked :D thank youuu !! now i think that i should begin to develop some tools in my layer like search itenerary...how to proced ? and it's time for that , i mean i have now all what i need to begin the developement ?!!

Comment: sorry but where should i place the html page and the javascript code ? and about the code that u wrote between <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs"> and </Directory> ? where should i add it ?

Comment: if you have an exemple of a page html and a code javascript it will be greatful if you send it to me just to show me how to proced..thank you a looot :)